# exporting unity game as android APK issue

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, gradle

I am currently exporting my game as APK however I am coming across a lot of errors that seem a bit vague for me.

I am using the highest setting for the API and I am also making sure to enter the keystore password.

I am getting 3 errors which I will list below in the code blocks.

Can somebody help with that?

```
> Configure project :launcher
WARNING: The option 'android.enableR8' is deprecated and should not be used anymore.
It will be removed in a future version of the Android Gradle plugin, and will no longer allow you to disable R8.
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.3.10f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\build-tools\30.0.2\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.3.10f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platform-tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.3.10f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-29\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.3.10f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only

> Task :launcher:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:mainApkListPersistenceRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:generateReleaseResValues
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:generateReleaseResources
> Task :launcher:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:extractDeepLinksRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:parseReleaseLocalResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:desugarReleaseFileDependencies UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:extractDeepLinksRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:packageReleaseResources
> Task :launcher:mergeExtDexRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseLibraryResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:validateSigningRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:generateReleaseBuildConfig
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:processReleaseManifest
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:extractDeepLinksRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:javaPreCompileRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:mergeReleaseShaders
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:compileReleaseShaders
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:generateReleaseAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:packageReleaseAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:parseReleaseLocalResources
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:bundleLibResRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:mergeReleaseNativeLibs
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:stripReleaseDebugSymbols
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibResRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:generateReleaseRFile
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseNativeLibs UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:stripReleaseDebugSymbols UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseManifest
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseRFile UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:compileReleaseLibraryResources
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:bundleLibCompileRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:bundleLibRuntimeRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:processReleaseManifest
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibRuntimeRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:processReleaseResources
> Task :launcher:javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:lintVitalRelease
> Task :launcher:dexBuilderRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeDexRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseJavaResource UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseNativeLibs UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:stripReleaseDebugSymbols UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:packageRelease FAILED
68 actionable tasks: 27 executed, 41 up-to-date

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':launcher:packageRelease'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key mediabias from store "C:\Users\ahmed\Media Bias Game\user.keystore": Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.3.10f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\OpenJDK\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.3.10f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-5.6.4.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx7644m" "assembleRelease"

stderr[

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':launcher:packageRelease'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key mediabias from store "C:\Users\ahmed\Media Bias Game\user.keystore": Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
]
stdout[

> Configure project :launcher
WARNING: The option 'android.enableR8' is deprecated and should not be used anymore.
It will be removed in a future version of the Android Gradle plugin, and will no longer allow you to disable R8.
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.3.10f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\build-tools\30.0.2\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.3.10f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platform-tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.3.10f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-29\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only
Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.3.10f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only

> Task :launcher:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :launcher:mainApkListPersistenceRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:generateReleaseResValues
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:generateReleaseResources
> Task :launcher:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:extractDeepLinksRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:parseReleaseLocalResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:desugarReleaseFileDependencies UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:extractDeepLinksRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:packageReleaseResources
> Task :launcher:mergeExtDexRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseLibraryResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:validateSigningRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:generateReleaseBuildConfig
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:processReleaseManifest
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:extractDeepLinksRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:javaPreCompileRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:mergeReleaseShaders
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:compileReleaseShaders
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:generateReleaseAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:packageReleaseAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:parseReleaseLocalResources
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:bundleLibResRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:mergeReleaseNativeLibs
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:stripReleaseDebugSymbols
> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibResRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:generateReleaseRFile
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseNativeLibs UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:stripReleaseDebugSymbols UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseManifest
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseAssets
> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseRFile UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:compileReleaseLibraryResources
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:bundleLibCompileRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:FirebaseApp.androidlib:bundleLibRuntimeRelease
> Task :unityLibrary:javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:processReleaseManifest
> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibRuntimeRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:processReleaseResources
> Task :launcher:javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:compileReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:lintVitalRelease
> Task :launcher:dexBuilderRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeDexRelease UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseJavaResource UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseNativeLibs UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:stripReleaseDebugSymbols UP-TO-DATE
> Task :launcher:packageRelease FAILED
68 actionable tasks: 27 executed, 41 up-to-date
]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <2c6e9a95f1dd4e06ad71afcd2684dcb7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <2c6e9a95f1dd4e06ad71afcd2684dcb7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <2c6e9a95f1dd4e06ad71afcd2684dcb7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1[T] progress, System.String error) (at <2c6e9a95f1dd4e06ad71afcd2684dcb7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <2c6e9a95f1dd4e06ad71afcd2684dcb7>:0)
Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <2c6e9a95f1dd4e06ad71afcd2684dcb7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <2c6e9a95f1dd4e06ad71afcd2684dcb7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <2c6e9a95f1dd4e06ad71afcd2684dcb7>:0)
Rethrow as BuildFailedException: Exception of type 'UnityEditor.Build.BuildFailedException' was thrown.
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.CancelPostProcess.AbortBuild (System.String title, System.String message, System.Exception ex) (at <2c6e9a95f1dd4e06ad71afcd2684dcb7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <2c6e9a95f1dd4e06ad71afcd2684dcb7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <2c6e9a95f1dd4e06ad71afcd2684dcb7>:0)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at <2c6e9a95f1dd4e06ad71afcd2684dcb7>:0)
UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <c77ced6644e541b7ad3d7315a5e92a0a>:0)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because of 'android.enableR8' is deprecated. To remove it from gradle.properties file you have to go to Project Settings > Player > (Android Tab) > Other Settings > and marking "Custom Gradle Properties Template".

After that a gradleTemplate.properties file is generated at "Assets/Plugins/Android/gradleTemplate.properties".

In this file remove line 'android.enableR8' or comment it out and now make new fresh build.

This trick should work.

Comment: I have removed it  and still showing


´´´
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details

> Configure project :launcher
WARNING: The option 'android.enableR8' is deprecated and should not be used anymore.
It will be removed in a future version of the Android Gradle plugin, and will no longer allow you to disable R8.
´´´

Comment: export as a android project and then change it on android studio. In android studio you have more control on these things.